# Bash file script escaping user input

Tags: bash

This bash script when run on Mac terminal, it needs to ask for user input, then it needs to check if a a string `"PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME="user-input"` exists in a given file and if not it should exit the script.

```
echo -e "${YELLOW}enter app name${WHITE}"
    read name

line=grep $name /path/to/file/entrypoint.sh

if [[ line != "PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME=\"$name\"" ]] ; then
    exit 1
fi
```

It needs much tuning as I am not very familiar with bash scripts. any suggestions? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs a little tweaking:

```
echo -e "${YELLOW}enter app name${WHITE}"
read -r name

if ! grep -q PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME="\"$name\"" /path/to/file/entrypoint.sh; then
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: made changes as per your suggestions.  Thanks!

Comment: @codeforester also: you probably want to use `fgrep` instead of `grep` because accidental special regex syntax in `$name` can do funny things to your `grep`. Furthermore you also should  consider using `-x` because you want to match the entire line, right? (To avoid false positives from substring matches).

Comment: @codeforester this answer failed to exit the script when the line is not found which is what is needed as per the original post.

Comment: @FredJ. - changed `grep` to `! grep`.  That should do it!